# Norm Convergence of Partial Sum Operator on Schwartz Space

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let's define the partial sum operator $S_R$ as
$$ (\widehat{S_R f}) = \chi_{B_R}\widehat{f}. $$

I need to prove that for $2 < p < \infty$ and $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, the Schwartz space, then $\|S_R f - f\|_p \rightarrow 0$ as $R \rightarrow \infty$.  Based on the line of questions, I think I basically need the two following facts:

1. $\|S_R f\| \leq C_p \|f\|_p$ for all $1 < p < \infty$,
2. Hausdorff-Young Inequality: If $f \in L^p$, $1 < p < 2$, then $\widehat{f} \in L^{p^\prime}$ and
   $$ \|\widehat{f}\|_{p^\prime} \leq \|f\|_p .$$

My struggle is regarding how to use 2., which was given with the advice to use said inequality to estimate $\|S_Rf - f\|_p$ in terms of its Fourier transform.  That confuses me as it seems on the wrong side of the inequality to get my desired result in any case.  Any help and/or advice would be a great help.  Thank you.

Comment: Based on the definition of it's Fourier transform, then we'd get $S_R f = D_R * f(x)$, where $D_R(x) = \sin (2\pi Rx) / (\pi x)$.

Answer (score 1):

2. says that $\|g\|_{q} \leq \|\hat{g}\|_{q'}$ for $q > 2$, take $q=p,g=S_rf-f$

(from that $\hat{f}\in S$ we get that $|\hat{f}(x)| \le C/(1+ x^2)$ obtaining a bound for $\|\hat{g}\|_{q'}$)

Comment: So let me see if I can follow this argument:  when we have $\|g\|_p \leq \| \hat{g}\|_p$, I then take $\int |\hat{g}|^p$ and break it up into $\int_{|x| \leq \delta}  +  \int_{|x| > \delta}$.  For $|x| \leq \delta$  the integrand is entirely zero if $R$ is big enough, and for $|x| > \delta$ I can use the given bound on the fourier transform of $f$ to make that integral small.  Is that the idea?